# delayed_job_active_record won't execute delayed code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

I am working with `delayed_job_active_record` gem.  I want to delay requests to an external API. Even though my job is added to database, and `rake jobs:work` runs it and removes it from the database, the actual delayed code from my `messages_controller.rb` is never executed.

If I if I drop the `.delay` from the controller methods, the code executes as expected and my tests all pass.

```
# messages_controller.rb
require 'zendesk'

class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  layout "application"

  # /suport/contact-us
  def contact_us
    zendesk = MyApp::Zendesk.new
    zendesk.delay.create_support_ticket(params[:message])

    # render page
    respond_to do |format|
      flash[:notice] = "Email sent successfully!" if @sent
      format.html { render "pages/support/contact-us" }
    end
  end
end

# zendesk.rb
require 'zendesk_api'

module MyApp
  class Zendesk
    attr_accessor :client

    def initialize(*args)
      @client = create_client
    end

    # contact-us ticket methods
    def create_support_ticket(params={})
      unless params.blank? || @client.blank?
        # get or create user_id for submitter
        params[:requester_id] = check_user_exists(params)

        begin
          ticket = @client.tickets.create(
            subject: "Support Ticket",
            comment: { value: params[:message] },
            submitter_id: params[:requester_id],
            requester_id: params[:requester_id],
            assignee_id: 201578811,
            status: "new",
            fields: [
              {id: 20887016, value: "Support"},
              {id: 20966436, value: "New"}])
          return ticket
        rescue => e
          Airbrake.notify e
        end
      else
        return false
      end
    end
  end
end
```

*** UPDATE ***
I tried launching my rails server without a worker running, and when invoking the job manually via `Delayed::Job.last.invoke_job`, I see this error:

```
Delayed::DeserializationError: Job failed to load: undefined class/module MyApp::. Handler: "--- !ruby/object:Delayed::PerformableMethod\nobject: !ruby/object:MyApp::Zendesk\n  client: !ruby/object:ZendeskAPI::Client\n    config: !ruby/object:ZendeskAPI::Configuration\n      client_options: {}\n      cache: !ruby/object:ZendeskAPI::LRUCache\n        size: 1000\n        store: {}\n        lru: []\n      url: https://REDACTED/api/v2\n      username: REDACTED\n      password: REDACTED      retry: true\n      logger: !ruby/object:Logger\n        progname: \n        level: 0\n        default_formatter: !ruby/object:Logger::Formatter\n          datetime_format: \n        formatter: \n        logdev: !ruby/object:Logger::LogDevice\n          shift_size: \n          shift_age: \n          filename: \n          dev: !ruby/object:IO {}\n          mutex: !ruby/object:Logger::LogDevice::LogDeviceMutex\n            mon_owner: \n            mon_count: 0\n            mon_mutex: !ruby/object:Mutex {}\n    callbacks:\n    - !ruby/object:Proc {}\n    resource_cache: {}\nmethod_name: :create_support_ticket\nargs:\n- !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters\n  name: ben\n  email: myemail@aol.com\n  reason: General\n  message: test\n"
        from /vendor/bundler/gems/delayed_job-4.0.0/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:97:in `rescue in payload_object'
```

I tried adding `require 'zendesk'` to a `config/initializers/custom.rb`, but the error persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose your `create_client` method is instantiating the Api object. Its quite possible that the Api instance is not valid since the process in which delayed jobs runs is asynchronous.

That said, you should create a new Zendesk Api instance in `create_support_ticket`.
Such as

```
def create_support_ticket(params={})
  @client = create_client
  unless params.blank? || @client.blank?
  ...
end
```

Comment: I have posted an update to the question, but I think you are correct that this will also be a problem.

Comment: does the `module MyApp` resides in separate .rb file? If not you should create it in /lib/my_app.rb and require lib in application.rb

Comment: yes, `module MyApp` is in `/lib/my_app.rb`, and `lib` is already auto-loaded with `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)` in `application.rb`